# Have two table cells ask and reply

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cells

I am trying to create a table view that has questions and replies but with the replies nested in slightly under the question.

I am calling the data from firebase but don't know how I would show that info in the table view. I have 2 cells set up with the look I want but can only populate either the questions or the answers.

I am still learning and the code is wrong because I know the second part won't be called after the return but it shows my 2 cells and if I comment out one of them then it shows the other no problem.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me or point me in the right direction, please.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = postsQuestion[indexPath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionsCell") as? QuestionsCell {

        if let img = MainInfoVC.imageCache.object(forKey: post.userCommentImage as NSString) {
            cell.configurePost(post: post, img: (img ))
            return cell
        }else {
            cell.configurePost(post: post)
            return cell
        }
    }else {
        return QuestionsCell()
    }

    let postRs = postsReplys[indexPath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReplyCell") as? ReplyCell {

        if let img = MainInfoVC.imageCache.object(forKey: post.userCommentImage as NSString) {
            cell.configureReplyPost(post: postRs, img: (img ))
            return cell
        }else {
            cell.configureReplyPost(post: postRs)
            return cell
        }
    }else {
        return QuestionsCell()
    }
}
```

Below is my Data that is being saved to firebase.

[image: Firebase Data]

and my code to call the data.

```
let postReg = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS
    postReg.child("\(subStr!)").child("question").queryOrdered(byChild: "date").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        self.postsQuestion = []

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {

                let postDictQ = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                let keyQ = snap.key
                let postQ = Post(postKey: keyQ, postData: postDictQ!)
                self.postsQuestion.append(postQ)
            }
        }
        self.postsQuestion.sort(by: {$0.date > $1.date})
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })



    let postReply = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.child("\(subStr!)").child("question")


    postReply.queryOrdered(byChild: "date").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {

                if snap.hasChild("replies") {
                    let snapID = snap.key

                    let refToReply = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.child("\(subStr!)").child("question").child(snapID).child("replies")

            refToReply.queryOrdered(byChild: "date").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

                let postDictR = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                let keyR = snap.key
                let postR = Post(postKey: keyR, postData: postDictR!)
                self.posts.append(postR)
                print("Tony: Snapshot Reply\(snapshot)")
            })
                }else {
                    print("Tony: No Replies")
            }
        self.posts.sort(by: {$0.date > $1.date})
        self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
```

This is how I want it to look in the View.

[image: View]

Comment: You need to check which cell you need according to some property of your post or your post cell type

Comment: Why are your questions in one array and your replies in another array? Why aren't the replies together with their associated post? Until you have a useful data model, it will be difficult to show the data in your table view.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. @rmaddy I understand, but Because I am new to trying to call the data this way I am trying to learn the best way. I have now included my database structure so you can see. I do nest the reply in the correct question id but didn't know I would be better putting them in the same array I have also added my code that calls the data from the database and changed the second one to append to the same array as the first would that be right?